# Nodejs https socket.io

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

here is my story:
- I have a website with SSL: https://domain.com
- And I want to make a live chat, so I uped linux server with node.js
- For linux server I made a self-signed certificate
Here is my server code (not all ofc, just basics):

```js
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
    requestCert: true
};

var app = express(options);
var server = https.createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server).listen(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connectedToServer', { conncted: true });
});
```

Here is my client code:

```js
var socket = io.connect('https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX', {secure: true, port:80});
socket.on('connectedToServer', function (data) {
    socket.emit('firstTimeConnected', id);
});
```

OK! and I have an error on client side: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(if I run client with http, - WS works but got alert about "Mixed Content", which is blocked by browser).
Really thanks 4 ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks strange. I'm not sure if it does what you think it does.
Also I'm not sure why are you listening on port 80 instead of the default 443. Do you want to always use URLs like https://www.examle.com:80/?

Try something like this:

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
    requestCert: true
};
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('https').Server(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

and now call `listen` on `server`:

```
server.listen(...);
```

And use default ports (80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS) unless you want to include the port explicitly in every URL.

Comment: ok, get it. Changed everything like in ur example. But now i have an error on client: "net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE".  And the code is: var socket = io.connect('https://xxxxxxx', {secure: true, port:443});